# How to change value of the element if element has class?

Tags: jquery

I need to change the value attribute of the input if #new_user:

- has .artist-registration to artist
- has .team-registration to  artist_team
- has .consumer-registration to consumer

What is the most elegant solution to do that?

Thanks in advance!

```
<form id="new_user" class="artist-registration">
<input type="hidden" value="artist" name="user[profile_attributes][role]" id="user_profile_attributes_role">
</form>
```

Comment: Please define 'elegant,' if that's your criteria for judging the success of the answers.

Comment: What are the rules for changing the class?  Changing from "team-registration" to "artist_team" doesn't seem all that "elegant" itself.

Comment: If form has class then change the value? Don`t you like the name of class? Instead of writing artist-team-registration i`ve used team-registration :)
Thanks for commenting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear, but I think you're saying that if the form element has class "artist-registration" then set the input element's value to "artist", and so forth for the other class names?

If you know that `#new_user` will only ever have one class then something like this:

```
var val = ""; // default blank value will apply if no classes match

switch ($("#new_user").attr("class")) {
   case "artist-registration":
      val = "artist";
      break;
   case "team-registration":
      val = "artist_team";
      break;
   case "consumer-registration":
      val = "consumer";
      break;
}
$('#user_profile_attributes_role').val(val);
```

If it is possible that `#new_user` might have multiple classes then perhaps:

```
var val = "",
    $nu = $("#new_user");

switch (true) {
   case $nu.hasClass("artist-registration"):
      val = "artist";
      break;
   case $nu.hasClass("team-registration"):
      val = "artist_team";
      break;
   case $nu.hasClass("consumer-registration"):
      val = "consumer";
      break;
}
$('#user_profile_attributes_role').val(val);
```

The latter will set the value according to which class is matched *first*, i.e., if the form had all three classes then "artist-registration" would take priority.

Comment: That`s what i need but it doesn`t work for me. Maybe it`s because classes to #new_user adding also with jquery with click function?

Comment: Where you place my code will matter. I'm not sure what you mean about the click function. Perhaps you could setup a demo at http://jsfiddle.net so that we can see what you're trying to do? E.g., here's a demo of my code working: http://jsfiddle.net/FzA4n/

Answer (score 0):

Using [jQuery](http://jquery.org):

```
var $input = $('#new_user');
$input.filter('.artist-registration').val('artist');
$input.filter('.team-registration').val('artist_team');
$input.filter('.consumer-registration').val('consumer');
```

The first line finds your `<input>` element. `$input` is strictly speaking a jQuery element set.

In each of the following lines, `filter()` returns a reduced element set whose elements match the given CSS selector. This set is empty in the two cases where the named class does not match the actual class of your `input` element.

The `val()` function then updates the value of every element in the given set. For the two unmatching calls, the set is empty, so the calls are a no-op.

Comment: That does look elegant, only four lines (with all the conditionals and loops hidden away in jQuery's internals), but I think the idea is to set the value of the input element inside the form.

Comment: Yes it`s nice, but i am to change the input element inside #new_user form as nnnnnn correctly mentioned. 
Thanks